# Maintain padding between shape on scale in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, scale, margin

I would like to scale multiple shapes, but locking the padding between them. Is this possible within Illustrator?

For example:

[image]

Comment: Relative or absolute?

Comment: 2 things come to mind. Scale it by moving points using the Direct Selection Tool. Of course this retains the corner radius too, and that might not be what you want... The other idea is a double stroke in that one object. One stroke that has the background color and another white stroke on top of it. Then turn off "Scale Strokes & Effects", like in WELZ answer. That way you could just normally scale it and the stroke and it's "padding" would say the same size.

Answer (score 1):

If you scale both shapes at the same time, they will stay the same relative distance to each-other.

If you don't want the (relative) size of the strokes to change,

Open the *Transform Panel* (**Window → Transform** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) and check **Scale Strokes & Effects**

[image: Transform Panel]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the object > path > **offset** option too. Just use the same value for both

Comment: You would have to then delete/hide the original one (because offset path creates a duplicate)